# Navigating nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to navigate a series of dictionaries nested in a list.

For example: `mydict = {'first':[{'second':2, 'third':3}, {'fourth':4}]}`

When I type `mydict.get('first')`, I get the whole list.

I can't use indexing to get each individual dictionaries in the list (i.e. `mydict.get(['first'][0]` returns the whole list, and `mydict.get(['first'][1])` returns an IndexError).

`mydict.get(['first'][0]['second'])` and`mydict.get(['first']['second'])` return TypeErrors.

So, if I wanted to call 'second' or 'fourth' or assign their values to variables, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For second:
`mydict['first'][0]['second]`

`['first']` returns the array
`[0]` returns the first object of the array
`['second']` gets the 'second' object

Perhaps try reshaping your data to something more convenient?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `mydict` isn't a series of dictionaries nested in a list. It is a dictionary that contains lists that, in turn, contain dictionaries.

So assuming you don't know which inner dictionary will contain the key you're looking for, you'd have to iterate over all the entries in the parent dictionary to find it. Something like:

```
desiredKey = 'second'
for listOfDict in mydict.values():
  for childDict in listOfDict:
    if desiredKey in childDict:
      print(childDict[desiredKey])
```

This will only work if the key you're looking for is always in the inner most dictionaries.